# Is there an equivalent of Vbscript execute statement in Java

Tags: java, vbscript

To start off, I know that Vbscript is interpreted and Java is compiled. But is there a way to do the tasks of vbscript 'execute' or 'eval' statements in Java? What I am trying to do is to save a piece of code in a variable, and try to execute the saved code during run time.

For eg, in vbscript,

a = "b = 10"

execute(a)

will assign the value 10 to a variable 'b'. If this is possible in java, I can handle a situation,I have got myself in to without redesigning the whole code. Request your help.

Comment: *"If this is possible in java, I can handle a situation,I have got myself in to without redesigning the whole code."* It may be worth posting a separate question outlining that situation and asking how / whether it could be resolved without runtime compilation (unless you know for **certain** that it cannot be; e.g., user-supplied code).

Comment: Yes. What I have to do is, I have to fetch multiple sets of values from an XML file to use in my code. It just so happens that, one of the values I retrieve is the name of a static variable(the value of which is defined in a class file.) I need to find a way to fetch the value of the static variable using the name of the variable I get from the XML file. I shall try posting this in a separate question.

Comment: @ QVSJ: Good news: You can do that without runtime compilation, via the `java.lang.reflect` package, and in particular via [`Field #get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html).

Comment: sorry. Connection issues.Could you check again please?

Answer (score 1):

No, Java has no equivalent to VBScript's `execute`.

You could do what you're outlining using [scripting for Java](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/), however, where you have a reasonably wide range of scripting languages to choose from.